# How to apply CSS styling to dynamically generated list (within mCustomScrollbar container)?

Tags: jquery, css, list, getjson, mcustomscrollbar

I'm dynamically generating a list from a MongoDB database using `getJSON()`.

The HTML being generated is correct and the related CSS styles are also correct.

The `<li>`'s should have images as backgrounds, but they aren't being applied.

In Firebug, I hover over the image background URL for each `<li>` and the image is previewed so I can tell the path is correct, they are just not being displayed.

The solutions I have come across involve using `listview('refresh')` but that seems to be a jQuery Mobile solution and I am just using standard jQuery.

Another solution I have seen is to use `addClass()` to an element after the function has run, but the element already has the correct class applied in the HTML, the style is just not being displayed.

Is there a 'standard' way of re-applying CSS after a function has run, or another approach to ensure that CSS is applied to a dynamically generated list?

**HTML**

```
<ul class="my_ul_class"></ul>
```

**jQuery** (external js file)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadListItems();
});

function loadListItems() {
    var href= "/url";
    $.getJSON("/path_to_python_script", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){
        $.each(results.my_key, function(k,v) {
            $("ul.my_ul_class").append("<li data-thing1=\"" + v + "\" class=\"prefix_" + v + "\"><ul class=\"nested\"><li class=\"hidden_li\"><p class=\"my_p_class\">text</p></li></ul></li>");
        });
    })
}
```

**Generated HTML**

```
<li class="prefix_1" data-thing1="1"><ul class="nested"><li class="hidden_li"><p class="my_p_class">text</p></li></ul></li>
```

Comment: What I would do is create a .css file generated by the back-end and returning the path to the file in your JSON callback. Then append that file to the head-tag using jQuery.

Comment: apply in css file this way: `ul.my_ul_class li{ color: blue;}` this will be applied to every list items.

Comment: Is it really working with li items added manually and only not working with dynamic generated items?

Comment: Css classes apply to both newly create and initial dom elements. You're searching on the wrong path.

Comment: @MujtabaHaider Good troubleshooting suggestion.  Yes, it is working when `<li>`'s are hardcoded. To test, I copied the generated `<li>`'s to the HTML file and removed the function and they displayed correctly.

Comment: @user1063287 please add a jsfiddle. That's the best way to understand your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution**

The solution involved modifying the placement of the [mCustomScrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/) function which was applied to the div container of the `<ul>`.

**jQuery** (external js file)

```
// wrap mCustomScrollbar in a custom function
function listScrollbar() {
$("#my_ul_container").mCustomScrollbar({
horizontalScroll:true,
set_width: false,
set_height: false,
scrollInertia:550,
advanced:{
updateOnBrowserResize:true,
updateOnContentResize:true,
autoExpandHorizontalScroll:false,
autoScrollOnFocus:true
}
})
}

// dynamically generate <li>'s
function loadListItems() {
var href= "/url";
$.getJSON("/path_to_python_script", {cid: href, format: 'json'}, function(results){
$.each(results.my_key, function(k,v) {
$("ul.my_ul_class").append("<li data-thing1=\"" + v + "\" class=\"prefix_" + v + "\"><ul class=\"nested\"><li class=\"hidden_li\"><p class=\"my_p_class\">text</p></li></ul></li>");
});
// call the mCustomScrollbar function
listScrollbar()
})
}

// call loadListItems
$(document).ready(function() {
loadListItems();
});
```